# Submitting HTML array to jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an HTML array and I want to submit it via jQuery ajax. When submitting and testing directly in the browser (just submitting the form as usual) I get the expected results and everything works. However, when submitting via ajax I get empty arrays.

I've tried serializing the form as well, but that produces the same result. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

#### My form

```
<form id="form-delete-previews" action="/delete/media/" method="DELETE">
@foreach($club->media as $image)
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb{{ $loop->iteration }}" name="image[]" value="{{ $image->id }}">
        <label for="cb{{ $loop->iteration }}">
            <img src="{{ $image->getUrl('sm') }}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" alt="">
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
.....
```

#### My javascript

```
$('#form-delete-previews').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
    swal({
        title: 'Are You Sure?',
        text: 'This can not be undone!',
        type: 'error',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#ee5254',
        confirmButtonText: 'Delete Images',
    }).then(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token },
            data: formdata,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                success();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                oops();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

#### My Laravel Controller

```
public function destroyMedia(Request $request)
{
    // return here for testing
    return response()->json([
        'type' => $request,
    ]);

    .....
}
```

#### This is what's returned

```
{
    "type": {
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

Not sure why, but if I change the method from `DELETE` to `POST` it works.

Any idea why `DELETE` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing the Request object in the controller. Instead, try:

```
// return here for testing
return response()->json([
    'type' => $request->get('image'),
]);
```

and see what is returned. Also, I would do this:

```
formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
console.log(formdata);
```

to see what is actually being sent.

Comment: I was only using `'type' => $request` to show everything that was being passed through. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your js checked the value of the formdata or try not to serialize the form and get it manually one by one